# PowerShell Replace not identifying string as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make my PowerShell script edit my appsetting.json file for my API.

The way I'm trying to do it is by fetching the content of the default appsettings.json and replacing the line:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```

...with a complete settings block looking something like this:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Kestrel": {
   "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
         "Url": "http://*:2201"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
         "Url": "https://*:2203",
         "SslProtocols": ["Tls12", "Tls13"],
         "Certificate": {
            "Subject": "SubjectName",
            "Store": "My",
            "Location": "CurrentUser",
            "AllowInvalid": "True"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To achieve this I'm using:

```
(Get-Content C:\test\appsettings.json) -Replace '"AllowedHosts": "*"', '"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Kestrel": {
   "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
         "Url": "http://*:2201"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
         "Url": "https://*:2203",
         "SslProtocols": ["Tls12", "Tls13"],
         "Certificate": {
            "Subject": "SubjectName",
            "Store": "My",
            "Location": "CurrentUser",
            "AllowInvalid": "True"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

It gives me this unwanted result:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Kestrel": {
   "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
         "Url": "http://*:2201"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
         "Url": "https://*:2203",
         "SslProtocols": ["Tls12", "Tls13"],
         "Certificate": {
            "Subject": "SubjectName",
            "Store": "My",
            "Location": "CurrentUser",
            "AllowInvalid": "True"
         }
      }
   }
}*"
```

I would like to know why this happens, even if there might be a better way to do this. I am of course also interested in suggestions of better ways of doing this :)

Thanks.

EDIT:
After suggestions in the answers, I've tried the following, but it complains about null-values. What's the right way to do it?

```
$appSettings | Add-Member -Name 'Kestrel' -Value '' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel | Add-Member -Name 'EndPoints' -Value '' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints | Add-Member -Name 'Http' -Value '' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.Http | Add-Member -Name 'Url' -Value 'http://*:2201' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints | Add-Member -Name 'HttpsInlineCertStore' -Value '' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore | Add-Member -Name 'Url' -Value 'https://*:2202' -MemberType NoteProperty
# $appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore | Add-Member -Name 'SslProtocols' -Value '["Tls12", "Tls13"]' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore | Add-Member -Name 'Certificate' -Value '' -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore.Certificate | Add-Member -Name 'Subject' -Value "SubjectName" -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore.Certificate | Add-Member -Name 'Store' -Value "My" -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore.Certificate | Add-Member -Name 'Location' -Value "CurrentUser" -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings.Kestrel.EndPoints.HttpsInlineCertStore.Certificate | Add-Member -Name 'AllowInvalid' -Value "True" -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content "C:\test\appsettings.json" -Force
```

Also, as you can see: I don't know how to achieve this line:

```
"SslProtocols": ["Tls12", "Tls13"],
```

Comment: Why are you trying to update a Json key value with regex ? This is definitely not what you should do, update it using `ConvertFrom-Json`, update the property value and `ConvertTo-Json` to convert it back.

Comment: You should definitely look at ```ConvertFrom-Json``` and ```ConvertTo-Json``` per @santiagosquarzon’s comment, but the reason your code is giving unexpected results is because the ```*``` in ```-Replace '"AllowedHosts": "*"', …``` is being treated as a regex wildcard symbol rather than a literal asterisk character. You can convert it into a literal search string instead of a pattern using ```$r = [regex]::Escape(‘"AllowedHosts": "*"’}``` and then ```… | -replace $r, ‘…’```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon
Well I simply don't know better :) I have only worked with txt-files before. But I'm working on a solution according to your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @mclayton
Thanks for explaining why I'm getting this error. I'm working at the better solution as suggested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have stated, `ConvertFrom-Json` is a better method of completing this. As an example I'll use this JSON to start:

```json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

You didn't say what values would be in "Line1/2/3", but let's say you want to add the following attributes:

```json
"HostIP1": "192.168.0.1",
"HostIP2": "192.168.0.2",
"HostIP3": "192.168.0.3"
```

This is the code you'd use:

```
$appSettings = Get-Content C:\test\appsettings.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$appSettings | Add-Member -Name HostIP1 -Value 192.168.0.1 -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings | Add-Member -Name HostIP2 -Value 192.168.0.2 -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings | Add-Member -Name HostIP3 -Value 192.168.0.3 -MemberType NoteProperty
$appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content C:\test\appsettings.json -Force
```

Now your `appsettings.json` should look like this:

```json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "HostIP1": "192.168.0.1",
  "HostIP2": "192.168.0.2",
  "HostIP3": "192.168.0.3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That cleared it up a bit, but since my values are a bit more complex, I have added them to my original post. I hope you can assist me further. Thanks.

Comment: @HammerOfSweden Don't use a single string when you want an array of strings. Replace `Add-Member -Name 'SslProtocols' -Value '["Tls12", "Tls13"]'` with `Add-Member -Name 'SslProtocols' -Value @("Tls12", "Tls13")`

Answer (score 0):

I tried a mix of the suggested solutions in this thread and the guide at this link: https://mattou07.net/posts/creating-complex-json-with-powershell/

...And came up with this solution:

```
$appSettings = Get-Content C:\test\appsettings.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$httpData = @{"Url"="http://*:2201"}

$httpsData = @{}
$httpsData.Add("Url","https://*:2203")
$httpsData.Add("SslProtocols",$("Tls12", "Tls13"))
$httpsData.Add("Certificate",@{"Subject"="SubjectName";"Store"="My";"Location"="CurrentUser";"AllowInvalid"="True";})

$endPointsData = @{}
$endPointsData.Add("Http",$httpData)
$endPointsData.Add("HttpsInlineCertStore",$httpsData)

$KestrelData = @{}
$KestrelData.Add("EndPoints",$endPointsData)
$appSettings | Add-Member -Name 'Kestrel' -Value $KestrelData -MemberType NoteProperty

$appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6 | Out-File "C:\test\appsettings.json"
```

It works fine. Only problems remaining are purely aesthetic as the indentation looks weird and the lines doesn't appear in the order I want them to. But I will post about that in a different thread if I can't find a solution.